# How to MAC filter an ethernet port connected to a repeater

Tags: ethernet

I live in a hostel that caters to tourists and have control of the primary router to which one of the residents (who is a heavy downloader) has connected a TP link repeater via Ethernet port. I am also connected via Ethernet port. I need to occasionally disconnect his repeater when I do my work so that I can have full use of broadband but the primary router wlan must still be accessible to the tourists.

The primary router filter settings are as this...

[image: Tp Link Repeater MAC filter serttings]

"Saliente" means outgoing and there is also an option for "entrante" which means incoming.

I would like to know how to set the source "MAC de origen" and destination "destino MAC".

Unfortunately the manual for the primary router ElTel is not complete on this issue. Any help?

Comment: configure it for Whitelist mode (permitir), and put in your work computers MAC as source, and the routers LAN MAC as the dest. That will cause the LAN switch to drop any traffic from MACs other than your computer going to the internet. This isn't really optimal because the traffic is being accepted on the LAN side (this device probably isn't sophisticated enough to firewall the LAN and WAN ports separately), but it won't congest the internet link.

Comment: Need an easier solution...whitelist mode is constantly changing with new guests every day accessing primary router. I need to block the repeater and simplest way I can figure is to use mac address against the repeater

Comment: I need to now what MAC to apply to saliente "origin" and "destino" and what MAC to apply to  entrante "origin" and "destino". My impression is that outgoing would be from primary to repeater and incoming would be repeater to primary?

Comment: There is no way to block a repeater by MAC, because a repeater is a layer1 device and does not have a MAC address. if the other guy has a Switch rather than a hub, then there is somthing you can do, but you can't block a hub and its hosts specifically without knowing of them in advance.

Comment: In other words the MAC address that is listed on the repeaters statistics page and back of repeater means nothing? when in repeater mode, AP mode, Client mode, etc?

Comment: you are not actually using a repeater. now this makes more sense.

Comment: No it has been set up as AP and it has another issue as well. When I shutdown and restart my comp my lan is blocked until I physically go and disconnect his ethernet cable and disconnect my ethrnet cable and THEN reconnect my ethernet cable and leave his disconected UNTIL my lan has made connection....go figure????? I had thought he may have a bad connector on his cable or God knows what...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, A **Repeater** is a hub. so-called **Wifi-repeaters**  more commonly called wifi-extenders) are an entirely differant thing. Hubs operate below the layer where there are MAC addresses, whereas Wifi operates at and above layer2. I was wondering how you had a hub with a configuration system  and any knowledge of MACs at all. a hub is like two cups on a string. it just puts out whatever gets put in without care as to whether those sounds are meaningful words.

Comment: Thnx for your reply...this is a TP-Link with only 1 lan ethernet port that canbe configured as a AP, Universal repeater or bridge, client mode and multiple SSID mode. It is not properly configured and is wrecking havoc with my ethernet port for some unknown reason as well as slowing down the wlan of the primary router ElTel, which is a really cheap router

Answer (score 0):

If your router offers a DHCP lease report, there's a chance you can guess the MAC address of connected router or network adapter of the person. It shows the mapping of Device name (Which is his computer name), assigned address, and MAC address.

Here is also where you can disable DHCP on a specific port.
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42570/discussion-on-answer-by-amirhossein-how-to-mac-filter-an-ethernet-port-connected).